# Porting QGIS C++ plugins to other QGIS installations

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

I developed a C++ plugin for QGIS using VC++ express 2008 and a QGIS dev release (1.9.90 alpha), my plugin works fine on this release and now I want to port it to other QGIS installations, so I copied the generated dll to the plugins directory of a QGIS 1.7.4 installation but it didn't get recognized by the extension manager.

Can you help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the plugin with the 1.7.4 libraries.