# How to install DTclassifier for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I want to install a dt-classifier plugin I have downloaded from a web page (http://gis-lab.info/qa/dtclassifier-eng.html). I unzipped it to the qgis plugin directory but it won`t show up in my plugin manager in Q-GIS.What can I do?

Comment: I have the same problem. I moved the plugins files into the /User/.qgis/.... directory, also to the /Program Files/Qgis/.... directory, in the appropriate folders, and it doesn't show up. I also added a path to the plugin's directory in the Options menu, and nothing. Anybody solved this??

Comment: Please don't add "I see that too" style problems as answers. You can make a comment on the question if you have additional details, or just mark the question up if it matches your situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in offline click [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline), may be it will help you..,

If you are in online click [here](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/python_in_qgis_tutorial1.html)

Comment: Its not a python plugin, but a c plugin. So it must be installed in the program path, like C:\Programs\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\plugins

Comment: I already tried the offline solution with the problem mentioned above. Trying the online solution I put the URL of the website where you can download the plugin as new repository. But there are no plugins shown for it.

Comment: I unzipped it to C:\Programs\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\plugins but havn`t installed. I thought this would be done with qgis.

Comment: No, the online method is only ment for python plugins. But my Qgis wont load the plugin. I get an error message that a procedure cannot be found. I guess you have to contact the author.

Comment: Did you make sure to go to "Manage Plugins" in then menue and check the box next to your plugin?

Comment: Yes, but it does not show up in the list.

Comment: Check out here [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24741/how-to-deploy-qgis-c-plugins]

Comment: Well, the plugin is intended vor Qgis 1.8.0, which runs here. But the files are from Feb and May 2012, at that time it was still the dev version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do exactly as described on the [plugin homepage](http://gis-lab.info/qa/dtclassifier-eng.html#Binary_files)?

> To work with plugin under Windows you need:
>
> - download and install QGIS 1.8 or higher (read more)
> - download the archieve with plugin and necessary libraries
> - (optionaly) check md5 sum: 
>     7622527e656373797080b4c40a9bb4f2 DTclassifier.7z
> - extract archive into QGIS plugins directory (usually C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\plugins)
>
> Linux binaries are also available. To work with plugin under Linux you need:
>
> - download and install QGIS 1.8 or higher.If packages for your distribution are not available — you need to compile QGIS from source
> - download the archieve with plugin: 32-bit binary (download) сompiled under 32-bit Slackware 13.1 using OpenCV 2.3.1
> - (optionaly) check md5 sum: 
>     b3089f69602b9b55652380728f7b2a3c dtclassifier-linux.tar.bz2
> - extract archive into QGIS plugins directory (usually /usr/lib/qgis/plugins)
>
> After installing you should run QGIS and enable the DTclassifier in Plugin Manager ("Modules → Manage plugins").

Comment: I tried the Windows part. But maybe the plugin expects some other OSGeo4W modules that are not in the standalone Installer Version.

Comment: What's your QGIS installation path and where did you extract the plugin to?

Comment: As mentioned above: C:\Programs\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\plugins. Thats where the other C++ plugins are. Starting Qgis I read in the protocol, that all plugins are successfully loaded, except DTclassifier.

Comment: I have the very same issue as Andre.. Anyone?